Parsing this sentence. Verb + だけで
女って聞くだけで構えちゃうんだよなオレ。。。
I am trying to understand it as follows: って here is the quotative particle right? As in
"When it comes to women/girls". So what does 動詞+だけで mean in this instance? I dont think it means "Only". 構えちゃうんだよ＝構えてしまう I think as well.
This sentence gives me the vibe of "When it comes to women, im just no good with them" But really, I cant parse it at all.


What's your understanding of the plain forms 構える and 聞く? "I dont think it means "Only"" - why not?

「～だけで」means " just by ...".
In this instance the sentence roughly means:
"Just by hearing the word 'woman' I get on guard (nervous)"
